# Поиск символа в input

Tags: jquery, javascript

Здравствуйте. Стоит такая задача, при вводе в input символы должны проверяться, и если найдены "." или ",", то фокус должен переключаться на другое поле. Пытаюсь сделать вот так, не получается.

```
$(function() {
    $('#input1').keyup(function(){ 
        if ($('$input1').is(":contains('.')")) {
            $('input2').focus();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#input1').on('keyup', function(){
    if($(this).val().match(/[\.,]/g)){
        $('#input2').focus();
    }
});
```

Comment: Работает, разобрался, огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй регулярными выражениями. И поставь событие onchange. А далее, код js\jquery(переключение фокуса и т.д.)

Comment: change срабатывает при потере фокуса, как я понимаю, а мне нужно, чтобы после ввода каждого символа срабатывала проверка

Comment: Да, точно.
Тогда альтернатива событие onkeypress.
Событие onkeypress срабатывает, когда клавиша на клавиатуре нажата и отпущена, что эквивалентно совместному действию onkeydown и onkeyup.

Comment: ну так в коде, который я написал используется "keyup", по сути проверка при нажатии идет, а вот поиск символа точки и запятой орагнизовать не получается